# How do I get "JRLbr6THaTI", the id of the link using regular expression?

Tags: python-3.x, url

`link='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRLbr6THaTI'`
`anotherlink='https://www.youtu.be/JRLbr6THaTI'`

Get only the id of the above URLs using regex.

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient: `[\w]+$`

Comment: how can i reverse the effect?

Comment: which function should I use?